# How to place dynamo db records in a SQS queue to trigger lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda that scans through items present in a dynamo table and does some post processing with that. While this works fine due to smaller number of entries in the table, it will soon grow and the 15 minute timeout will be reached.

I am considering utilizing a SQS but not sure how i can place records from the table to SQS which will then trigger the lambda concurrently.

Is this a feasible solution? Or should i just create threads with the lambda and process it, again unsure if this will count towards the 15 minute limit

Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB streams is a perfect use-case for this, every item added or modified will enter the stream and in turn will trigger your Lambda function that does the pre-processing, but of course it strongly relies on your particular use-case.

If for example you require all the data from the table, you can make useful aggregations and contain those aggregates in a single item. Then instead of having to Scan the table to get all the items, you just do a single GetItem request which already holds your aggregate data.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html

Comment: Thank you so much for suggestion! In line to the second comment, i could write a separate lambda which will retrieve required data from the dynamo table (this will be based on some filter) and push it to the queue. Then from the queue, i could enable the lambda to process table entries in batch of say 5 and have to run for the remaining entries in queue in a similar way, correct?

Comment: You need to explain your use case in more detail, be specific about your needs.

Comment: I have a dynamo table that holds various tokens along with an expiration time value. The existing tool consists of a lambda that scans through ALL the tokens in the table and compares with the current date and if it is within a certain window it renews the token using a few api calls. This roughly takes up about 8 minutes but this table will soon grow with more tokens and that is the context for why i am exploring a queue solution. initial idea was to create another lambda that will query the tokens that are expiring and add to the queue and have the second lambda poll from the queue & process

Answer (score 2):

As @LeeHannigan says, use [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) to capture your table's CRUD events. Streams has traditionally had 2 targets to consume these change events:  Lambda and Kinesis.

But what about a SQS destination?  [EventBridge Pipes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes.html) adds EventBridge as another way to consume DynamoDB streams.  EB Pipes, a new integration service, would have the DynamoDB Stream as its [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes-dynamodb.html) and SQS as its [target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes-event-target.html).

The flow would be `DynamoDB Streams -> EB Pipes -> SQS -> Lambda`.